# Calculate cumulative sum after a set period of time

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, cumulative-sum

I have a data frame with COVID data and I'm trying to make a column calculating the number of recovered people based off of the number of positive tests.

My data has a location, a date, and the number of tests administered/positive results/negative results each day. Here's a few lines using one location as an example (the real data has several months worth of dates):

```
loc    date        tests  pos  neg  active
spot1  2020-04-10  1      1    0    5
spot1  2020-04-11  2      1    1    6
spot1  2020-04-12  0      0    0    6
spot1  2020-04-13  11     1    10   7
```

I want to make a new column that cumulatively counts each positive test in each location 14 days after it is recorded. On 2020-04-24, the 5 active classes are not active anymore, so I want a recovered column with 5. For each date I want the newly nonactive cases to be added.

My first thought was to try it in a loop:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(loc) %>%
  mutate(rec = for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  #getting number of new cases
  x <- df$pos[i]
  #add 14 days to the date
  d <- df$date + 14
  df$rec <- sum(x)
})
```

As you can see, I'm not the best at writing for loops. That gives me a bunch of numbers, but bear very little meaningful relationship to the data.

Also tried it with map_dbl:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(loc) %>%
  mutate(rec = map_dbl(date, ~sum(pos[(date <= . + 14) & date >= .])))
```

Which resulted in the same number printed on the entire rec column.

Any suggestions? (Sorry for the lengthy explanation, just want to make sure this all makes sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data shows that -

- you have all continuous dates despite `0` tests (12 April)
- `Active` column seems like already a `cumsum`

Therefore I think you can simply use `lag` function with argument `14`

example code

```
df %>% group_by(loc) %>% mutate(recovered = lag(active, 14)) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: Glad to have been help.  Please also feel free to mark/accept the answer as usually desired on SO for benefit of future/other users.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data %>%
    mutate(date = as_date(date),
           cut = cut(date, '14 days') %>%
    group_by(loc) %>%
    arrange(cut) %>%
    mutate(cum_pos = accumulate(pos, `+`)) # accumulate(pos, sum) should also work
```

As a general rule of thumb, avoid loops, especially within mutate - that won't work. Instead of `map_dbl` you should check out `purrr::accumulate`. There's specialized functions for this in R's base library such as `cumsum` and `cummin` but their behavior is a lot less predictable in relation to purrr's.

Comment: P.S.: if you're dealing with time series data  and feel like you need to be more explicit about it, you should try {tsibble} for time-aware tibbles and this baby: https://github.com/DavisVaughan/slider

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregate to sum the specific column and then applying
cut in order to set a 14 day time frame for each sum:

```
df <- data.frame(loc = rep("spot1", 30),
       date = seq(as.Date('2020-04-01'), as.Date('2020-04-30'),by = 1),
       test = seq(1:30),
       positive = seq(1:30),
       active = seq(1:30))

 output <- aggregate(positive ~ cut(date, "14 days"), df, sum)

 output
```

Console output:

```
 cut(date, "14 days") positive
1           2020-04-01      105
2           2020-04-15      301
3           2020-04-29       59
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
library(dplyr)
date_seq <- seq(as.Date("2020/04/01"), by = "day", length.out = 30)
pos <- rpois(n = 60, lambda = 10)

mydf <-
  data.frame(loc = c(rep('loc1', 30), rep('loc2', 30)),
             date = date_seq,
             pos = pos)
head(mydf)

getPosSum <- function(max, tbl, myloc, daysBack = 14) {
  max.Date <- as.Date(max)
  sum(tbl %>%
        filter(date >= max.Date - (daysBack - 1) &
                 date <= max.Date & loc == myloc) %>%
        select(pos))
}

result <-
  mydf %>%
  group_by(date, loc) %>%
  mutate(rec = getPosSum(max = date, tbl = mydf, myloc = loc))
```